# creating a service with yo angular:factory test fails to load testProvider

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-factory

i am trying to inject a factory onto a controller using the angular fullstack generator and am having issues with the provider not found, where am i going wrong?
i created an app with

npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack

yo angular-fullstack chatApp

yo angular:factory test

app/scripts/services/test.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chatApp')
.factory('test', function () {
// Service logic
// ...

 var meaningOfLife = 42;

 // Public API here
  return {
  someMethod: function () {
    return meaningOfLife;
  }
  };
  });
```

so where do i load the factory i am trying to load in the main.js file like so

app/scripts/controllers/main.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chatApp')
 .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, test) {
console.log(test);
   $scope.messages = 'this is a hardcoded test';
 });
```

app/scripts/main.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('chatApp', [
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngSanitize',
'ngRoute',

])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
 $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/main',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
  .when('/signup', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/signup',
    controller: 'SignupCtrl'
  })
  .when('/settings', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/settings',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
    authenticate: true
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/about',
    controller: 'SettingsCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });

 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

 // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
 $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$location', function($q, $location) {
  return {
    'responseError': function(response) {
      if(response.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
      else {
        return $q.reject(response);
      }
    }
   };
   }]);
 })
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {

 // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next) {

  if (next.authenticate && !Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
    $location.path('/login');
  }
  });

  console.log($location);

});
```

Error is:

```
304 Not Modified
    14ms    
angular.js (line 7997)

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: testProvider <- test
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.11/$injector/unpr?p0=testProvider%20%3C-%20test
minErr/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3543
getService@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3670
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3548
getService@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3670
invoke@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3697
instantiate@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3718
@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6777
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:907
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6228
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5637
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5542
boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5656
controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6248
update@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:865
Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:12245
```

Comment: seems as if the test.js is not being loaded, but i dont know how to make it load

Comment: seems as if the service script isnt being included into the main view file how do i make grunt include newly gcreated directives,services, etc into the main application and thus be available (seems as if the test.js is not being loaded, but i dont know how to make it load, you can see in the link at the bottom how the test.js isnt there but user.js is [Heres a link to the app](http://hastebin.com/fiweyajaci.xml)

Answer (score 0):

i solved this
i was using thw wrong generator h
the correct one is 
yo angular-fullstack:factory test 
there is no yo remove function so you must manually remove created .js files and what was injected into main.html